# Nox App Player not connect with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

### command not execute

Now I am going to command prompt and go to the bin folder under the installation path of Nox App Player, and I input this command: `nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001`.

[image]

Comment: Is nox player running when executing this command or not?
I think you should load it before executing `connect` command.

Answer (score 19):

You need to find the correct port and use it. I faced the same problem so here is what I did.

1. Kill the server:

   ```
   nox_adb.exe kill-server
   ```
2. Now try to connect on any port number, say, 62001:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
   * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   * daemon started successfully *
   unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:62001:62001
   ```
3. Now try to use port 5037 as mentioned in the output above:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe kill-server
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:5037
   * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   * daemon started successfully *
   connected to 127.0.0.1:5037
   ```

It should work fine then.

Answer (score 3):

find the file location of nox and copy-it

write in cmd:

cd and write the location here

and

adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:5037

people write "nox.adb.exe" but it's 
false

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:5037
```

Answer (score 2):

I am solving this problem everyday by running `vscode` first and then running `nox`. then killing `adb.exe` process tree by Task manager and then running `nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001` `(or 127.0.0.1:52001)`. Doing all these steps several time everyday.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem and trying to connect nox player with studio, with many attempts I finally found perfect cure for this issue. You have to make sure adb version for both android sdk and nox player uses same.

If they are different, then make them same by replacing these files

```
(adb.exe, nox_adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll, AdbWinApi_.dll)
```

of nox player bin folder `(C:\Program Files\Nox\bin\Nox\bin)` from android sdk `(C:\Users\harvi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools).` And that's it nox player now easily connect with android studio.

*Note: create nox_adb file from adb.exe from sdk folder.*

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

*(xxxxx = port number, i used 62001)*

also

**Important to include "" (quotation marks)...**

```
"C:\Program Files\nox\Nox\bin\nox_adb.exe" connect 127.0.0.1:xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Praise be to God, it's finally fixed. I tried all the other solutions and none worked, I even tried updating to the latest version before. I guess updating doesn't update all the files.

The issue was the either adb.exe or nox-adb.exe had an issue, it's not the port that's the issue, it's the adb itself, poiting to a null location, it's weird how it got corrupted. replacing the DLLs as mentioned by a different answer didn't work for me, that's how I know it's the adb executables.

Anyways, the **solution** is to extract the adb.7z file that's in the bin folder and replace the old files, **that's it** :)

**Short answer**:

Extract "C:\Program Files\Nox\bin\adb.7z" & replace all

Comment: And worray! It solved my problem. Guess what, just upvoted your answer. It is worth to be seen by others.

Answer (score 1):

find adb.exe file path, open console and write: `C:\Users\petra\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` (it has to be your path to `adb file)\adb.exe` connect 127.0.0.1:62001 make sure nox is turned on and try this till you see:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
connected to 127.0.0.1:62001
```

Answer (score 0):

input this command : nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62025

Comment: Can you add a bit to your answer to explain why that may help?

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.
- Task Manager should open.
- Click "More details" from below.
- A larger list of apps should appear.
- Locate `adb.exe` select it then click 'End Task'.
- Restart Nox or do what @kundan's answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the adb.exe from **C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools** and renamed it to **nox_adb.exe** and pasted it in the **nox installation location** replacing the original one. after that it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I get:

- Nox-Player with Android 9
- Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Open terminal tab in Android Studio, type `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62025`, enter and it works

[image]

---

The **key** here is we have to find out the **real port** that is opened by Nox

In my case, it is 62025

Good luck!

---

**Update**

**DO NOT** use adb.exe of Nox. It conflicts with Android Studio. Actually, we don't need it because we got adb from Android Studio

I did try Nox-adb, it works for a period time but after that Android Studio **disconnected** it automatically